# can we use Lm317 1.25 ref for ext. reference of arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

I m trying to give ext ref. To Arduino using lm317 1.25 ref.
I  tried to do it. Iswt this voltage in programme too 
But when I run it it was just displaying 1.25
And der was no variation as I varie the resistance of potentiometer which is connected to A0
So plz help me.....
My Arduino chip is Atmega 8A

Comment: Please post your code, and also your schematic. As it is your question doesn't make a lot of sense. See [how to ask a good question](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2523/how-to-ask-a-good-question-for-arduino-stack-exchange).

Answer (score 1):

yes but you have to use the analogReference(EXTERNAL); command otherwise it will short the default VCCref volatage with the external (i assume this will cause damage.. dunno never done that. yet...)
also if you use a 1.25v reference just remember that that will be the maximum voltage you can measure up to. 
theres a couple of things you can do

1 use a voltage devider circuit to drop the max voltage out of your sensor(potentiometer) down to about 1.25v

2 put a series resistor betweent vcc and the positive terminal of your potentiometer (creating a voltage devider between the resistor and the full resistance of the potentiometer)

3 and probably the easiest connect the positive of the potentiometer to the lm317 /reference pin so that its output will be between Aref and GND this is the best option as it will be the most stable as its output will be in propotion to any fluctuation of the lm317

as in 3. the same can be done if using the internal Vref conect the pot to Aref (but remember that it has a limited current output so be carefull not to draw too much by using low resistance pots or many in parallel)

Comment: Kk i tried it. But the thing is I came to know my adc is not working means all the 6 pins.

Comment: The are always giving 1023 for any value . I tried also a basic programme of potentiometer but the thing is even there it was giving maximum value.....plz is there a solution for this. I also saw dat d aref pin is not shorted anywhere.

Comment: please post the relevant portion/s of your code for pot reading and void setup and variables. enough to compile please cheers